# Hi i got a problem on schema object to display fields of required obj

Tags: apex, schema

Hi all I want to create a input field (where we enter sobject names) when data is entered we have to display all the fields in that object in  the form of picklist

```
public class SchemaDynamicField {

    public string asd {set;get;}
    public map<string,schema.SObjectField> fldmap{set;get;}
    public list<selectoption> fields{set;get;}

    public SchemaDynamicField(){
          schema.describeSobjectResult result = account.SobjectType.getDescribe();
          fldmap = result.fields.getmap();
          fields = new list<selectoption> ();

          for(string  s : fldmap.keyset()){
            selectoption op = new selectoption (s,s);
            fields.add(op);
          }
   }

    public void getFields () {

        fields.clear ();
        schema.describeSobjectResult result = asd.SobjectType.getDescribe();
        fldmap = result.fields.getmap();
        fields = new list<selectoption> ();

        for(string  s : fldmap.keyset()){
              selectoption op = new selectoption (s,s);
              fields.add(op);
        } 
    }
}
```

> error is :Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject:
>   String

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
schema.describeSobjectResult result = asd.SobjectType.getDescribe();
```

asd is defined as a string and there is no property on String of sObjectType

did you mean to do

```
schema.describeSobjectResult result = account.SobjectType.getDescribe();
```

Not sure what you are trying to get at here but the `asd` needs to be replaced with an sObject.

If you are trying to get the sObjectType for a string you can use global describe to get the type from the map like:

```
 Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(asd);
```

Which will return the sObjectType

Comment: My requirement is when i enter a Sobject  name  in input text in vf page

Comment: ok i will try it

Comment: My requirement is when i enter a Sobject  name  in input text in vf page all the fields of that sobject should be in a picklist

Comment: @nunnanaresh - Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**You should the global describe and pass the sObject token for describing the object dynamically.**

> Find the updated code below and check if this works
>
> Check this line of code: fldmap =
>   Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(asd).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

```
public class SchemaDynamicField {

    public string asd {set;get;}
    public map<string,schema.SObjectField> fldmap{set;get;}
    public list<selectoption> fields{set;get;}

    public SchemaDynamicField(){
        schema.describeSobjectResult result = account.SobjectType.getDescribe();
        fldmap = result.fields.getmap();
        fields = new list<selectoption> ();

        for(string  s : fldmap.keyset()){
            selectoption op = new selectoption (s,s);
            fields.add(op);
        }
   }

    public void getFields () {

        fields.clear ();
        fldmap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(asd).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        fields = new list<selectoption> ();

        for(string  s : fldmap.keyset()){
            selectoption op = new selectoption (s,s);
            fields.add(op);
        } 
    }
}
```